# Control ALSA Volume on unity-control-center sound (not Pulse Audio)

Tags: unity, sound, software-center, pulseaudio, alsa

I just managed to disable *Pulse Audio* to get free of its (frustrating) re-sampling feature. Everything is good with *ALSA*, except for I have to rely on `alsamixer` for volume control. Is there a way to use `unity-control-center sound` instead (like if I was using *Pulse Audio*)?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The [code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-control-center-team/unity-control-center/trunk/view/head:/panels/sound/cc-sound-panel.c#L32) directly uses PulseAudio.